# Is this a bedbug or a book lice or what?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

So basically i found this thing in my home. It's super small so I had to zoom it for you. Whiteish/yellowish colour. We had bedbug problem back in our dorms and I'm worried I somehow managed to transfer them home but I don't know if it's a bedbug nymph or a book lice or what kind of insect, so I'd really appreciate someone's opinion on this.

Edit: It's really small, like. really small. my mother wouldn't even see it and thought me crazy. Just zoom made it look bigger. I'd say 1.5mm maximum at the very best. Moves kinda quickly and I thought it jumped two times when i was trying to capturing but maybe it was just me doing it to it. Living in Europe, Slovakia specifically.

[image: ???]

Comment: Only except its extra long antannae this bug seems to be Cimex sp.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. How small is it? Where do you live? (You can edit those info directly in your post with the 'edit' button).

Comment: Heya. I edited it so maybe that could add some input. I know how an adult bedbug looks like but this one baffles me cause of it's size, that's why I even thought it could be nymph stage

Answer (score 6):

This is not a bed bug, but some sort of book louse (order Psocoptera). Bed bugs have a more compact body shape, even in the early stages:
[image] (from http://www.bedbuginspectiongroup.com/facts/)

Compare this with a book louse, and I think it is much closer to your specimen:
[image]
(from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ABook_louse_01.JPG)

Also, here is a page comparing them: http://bedbugger.com/2008/03/04/book-lice/

Hope you stay bed bug free!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I shall calm myself down now. I'm moving tomorrow and I don't wanna infest everything where I go, my personality does the job good enough, who needs bed bugs with that. Thanks once again